# Uploading an image working, but also not working

Tags: php

I'm uploading a picture to the server from a form, it does upload the file to the server, but not into the correct directory.

I couldn't figure out what the problem could be, my syntax IS RIGHT.

```
$filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newfilename= $username."_".$itemid.".".$extension;
$desti="\\www\\tomiexpress\\uploaded_photos\\".$newfilename;
if(!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])&& move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $desti))
{
  echo "hellyeah";
}
```

So the file should land in the tomiexpress\uploaded_photos directory, but it lands in tomiexpress\ directory, also move_uploaded_file() is true.

Comment: *also echo $desti; looks correct, also tried with less slashes

Comment: Isn't it a bit late checking `!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])` after you have used its contents OR LACK OF THEM to build part of `$newfilename`

Comment: We also have no visibility of how OR if you populate `$username` and `$itemid`

Comment: This is an old messy code and i want to make it work.
     $sql = "SELECT id FROM shopitems2 WHERE imgpath = '$rand'";
     $itemid = $row['id']; 
      $username=$_SESSION['username'];
Heres the missing information, but it has nothing to do with the problem, i think.
The code also worked perfectly when i hosted a server with xampp on my pc, the problem appeared when i uploaded it onto another server. Only this one problem.

Comment: What if you try changing $desti to $desti = './uploaded_photos/'.$extension; This depends on where your php file is located and your document root setting... AND make sure the folder exists (and is named in the same case, in this instance all lower case) and that you have write permissions to the folder.

Comment: Also, i got a file, for example "user_788.jpg" (in the wrong folder), it does exist on the server, i can view it and it is the correct picture, but when i type in its URL in the browser, it can't find the file.